# Why is my custom allocator slower, than default allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm new to C++ allocators and spent a whole day, trying to build my own one. I took A. Alecsandrescu Loki allocator as a stepping stone and followed [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement) tutorial. Eventually, I made a working allocator and was about to take some rest, when it turned out that this custom allocator is terribly slower than the default one. This is the whole code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
using namespace std::chrono;

using uchar = unsigned char;

class Chunk 
{
private:    

    friend class FixedAllocator;

    void init(size_t blockSize, uchar blocks);

    void release();

    void* allocate(size_t blockSize);

    void deallocate(void* p, size_t blockSize);

    inline bool hasBlock(void* p, size_t chunkLen) const
    {
        uchar * pc = static_cast<uchar*>(p);
        return (pData <= pc) && (pc <= (pData + chunkLen));
    }

    inline bool releasable(uchar numBlocks) const
    {
          return blocksAvailable == numBlocks;    
    }

    uchar* pData;

    uchar firstAvailableBlock, blocksAvailable;    
};


void Chunk::init(size_t blockSize, uchar blocks)
{
     // for n of Ts it will allocate n * sizeof(T) memory
    pData = new uchar[blockSize * blocks];
    firstAvailableBlock = 0;
    blocksAvailable = blocks;
    uchar i = 0;
    uchar* p = pData;
    // used by allocate method to move forward firstAvailableBlock 
    for (; i != blocks; p += blockSize) 
    {
          *p = ++i;
    }
}


void Chunk::release()
{
    ::operator delete(pData);
}


void* Chunk::allocate(size_t blockSize)
{
     if (!blocksAvailable) return 0;
     // move firstAvailableBlock one block ahead
    uchar* pResult = pData + firstAvailableBlock * blockSize;
    firstAvailableBlock = *pResult;
    --blocksAvailable;
    return pResult;
}


void Chunk::deallocate(void* p, size_t blockSize)
{
    uchar* toRelease = static_cast<uchar*>(p);
    // find last but one available block
    firstAvailableBlock = static_cast<uchar>((toRelease - pData) / blockSize);
    ++blocksAvailable;
}


class FixedAllocator 
{
private:
    size_t blockSize;
    uchar blocks;
    using Chunks = std::vector<Chunk>;
    Chunks chunks;
    Chunk* allocChunk;
public:
    FixedAllocator();
    ~FixedAllocator();
    void init(size_t blockSize, size_t pageSize);
    void * allocate();
    void deallocate(void* p);
};


FixedAllocator::FixedAllocator():
    blockSize(0),
    blocks(0),
    chunks(0),
    allocChunk(nullptr)
{
}


FixedAllocator::~FixedAllocator()
{
    Chunks::iterator it;
    for (it = chunks.begin(); it != chunks.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->release();    
    }
}


void FixedAllocator::init(size_t blockSize_, size_t pageSize)
{
     blockSize = blockSize_;
    size_t numBlocks = pageSize / blockSize;
    blocks = static_cast<uchar>(numBlocks);
}


void* FixedAllocator::allocate()
{
     if (!allocChunk || allocChunk->blocksAvailable == 0)
    {
        Chunks::iterator it = chunks.begin();    
        for (;;++it)
        {
            if (it == chunks.end())
            {
                 // allocate memory for one more chunk
                chunks.reserve(chunks.size() + 1);
                Chunk newChunk;  
                newChunk.init(blockSize, blocks);
                // add new chunk to memory pool
                chunks.push_back(newChunk);                
                // points to new just initiated chunk
                allocChunk = &chunks.back();
                break;
            }
            if (it->blocksAvailable > 0)
            {
                 // points to chunk with available blocks
                allocChunk = &*it;
                break;            
            }                   
        }
    }
    return allocChunk->allocate(blockSize);
}


void FixedAllocator::deallocate(void* p)
{
    size_t chunkLen = blocks * blockSize;
    Chunks::iterator it;
    int cPos = 0;
    for (it = chunks.begin(); it != chunks.end(); ++it, ++cPos)
    {
        if (it->hasBlock(p, chunkLen))
        {
            it->deallocate(p, blockSize);  
            if (it->releasable(blocks)) {
                it->release();
                chunks.erase(chunks.begin() + cPos);
                // allocChunk may point to deleted chunk
                // so, reset it
                if (!chunks.empty()) {
                    allocChunk = &chunks.back();
                } else {
                    allocChunk = nullptr;                
                }
            } else {
                // there are free blocks in chunk
                // so, reset allocChunk for fast search
                allocChunk = &*it;    
            }
            break;   
        }    
    } 
}


class SmallObjAllocator
{
public:
    SmallObjAllocator(size_t pageSize, size_t maxObjectSize);
    void* allocate(size_t numBytes);
    void deallocate(void* p, size_t numBytes);
private:
    FixedAllocator* pool;
    size_t maxObjectSize;
};


SmallObjAllocator::SmallObjAllocator(size_t pageSize, size_t maxObjectSize_):
    pool(nullptr),
    maxObjectSize(maxObjectSize_)
{
    pool = new FixedAllocator[maxObjectSize];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < maxObjectSize; ++i)
    {
          pool[i].init(i + 1, pageSize); 
    }
}


void* SmallObjAllocator::allocate(size_t numBytes) {
    if (numBytes > maxObjectSize)
    {
        return ::operator new(numBytes);    
    }    
    FixedAllocator& alloc = pool[numBytes-1];
    return alloc.allocate();
}


void SmallObjAllocator::deallocate(void* p, size_t numBytes)
{
    if (numBytes > maxObjectSize)
    {
        ::operator delete(p);   
        return; 
    }
    FixedAllocator& alloc = pool[numBytes-1];
    alloc.deallocate(p);
}


template<typename T, size_t numBlocks = 64>
class Allocator  
{
public:

    Allocator(){};

    template<typename U, size_t N>
    Allocator(Allocator<U, N> const&);

    template<typename U>
    struct rebind 
    {
        using other = Allocator<U, numBlocks>;
    };

    T* allocate(size_t cnt) 
    {
          return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
              allocator.allocate(sizeof(T) * cnt)
          );       
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, size_t cnt) 
    {
        allocator.deallocate(p, sizeof(T) * cnt);
    }

    void construct(T* p, T const& val) 
    {
        ::new((void *)p) T(val);         
    } 

    void destroy(T* p) 
    {
        return ((T*) p)->~T();        
    } 

    using value_type = T;

private:
    static SmallObjAllocator allocator;       
};


template<typename T, size_t numBlocks>
SmallObjAllocator Allocator<T, numBlocks>::allocator(numBlocks * sizeof(T), sizeof(T));


template<class List>
void test(std::string comment, List l)
{
    std::cout << comment;
    auto start_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        l.push_back(i);    
    }
    auto end_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end_time  - start_time).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
}


int main() {     
     test("default list ", std::list<int>());   
     test("list with custom allocator ", std::list<int, Allocator<int, 10000>>());
     return 0;
}
```

As you can see, in my client code I put some profiling and this profiling shows that default list is populated for 0ms, whereas the list with custom allocator is populated for 3ms. I thought that the whole trouble is with `deallocate` method and commented it out, but still got the very same picture. So, what may be the reason of such performance downgrade? What am I missing?

Comment: Profiling code is an art. It could be that the system one is doing some lazy allocation where it returns instantly and does the work later - or it is optomized away, or it is just very very well written

Comment: I tried even larger numbers - lists of 1e7 size. But in this case I could not even wait till the end. However, default allocator worked perfect even in this case.

Comment: You seem to perform a linear search in `allocate`.

Comment: Do you really think a good allocator iterates over every chunk when looking for a free one? Try researching "heap allocator design". Also have a look at [jemalloc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcWp5vwGlYU).

Comment: @VTT. This allocate method is almost a total clone of Alecsandrescu Loki allocate method - http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00671.html (line 00829).

Comment: @ RustyX. Thanks! I will have a look at this concept.

Comment: Do you have IDE like vs? Profile it there, see what takes so long.

Comment: For `std::list` your best bet is typically just going to be a simple constant-time free list. Just at a glance that allocator seems like it does much more work than necessary for a linked structure. Also sometimes the benefit of a custom allocator isn't to make allocation faster. Some trade extra time to allocate/free to improve locality of reference, e.g., on repeated traversals.

Comment: I checked `allocate` method. When I create for example 100 list items, linear search takes place only once. 99 times memory is allocated through `allocChunk` variable.

Comment: @DrunkCoder. "Also sometimes the benefit of a custom allocator isn't to make allocation faster. Some trade extra time to allocate/free to improve locality of reference, e.g., on repeated traversals." - great notice! Thanks!

Comment: @Jacobian Cheers! Also here is a simple constant-time FreeList implementation for you to play with. I didn't bother to adapt it to std::allocator's interface and it was just an example for a colleague to demonstrate the concept (not really production ready as it's not thread-safe, e.g.), but it might be useful to get your feet wet with custom allocators: https://paste.ofcode.org/35u7ez7qNDJy6j4StViaZYU. That said, it's worth taking it easy on custom allocators. I always found them a bit ugly since we're reaching under the data structure -- far more preferable to me is just have a data [...]

Comment: [...] structure which already allocates/frees memory in an efficient way. But a free list can come in handy -- it's the most basic but I personally find it the most useful custom allocator to speed up, say, the building of a linked structure.

Comment: @DrunkCoder. Thank you so much! I will have a look at FreeList implementation. At first glance it seems much simpler than my SmallObjAllocator. So, there is a lot of chance that it will work faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default allocator([std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)) is typically implemented as a relatively thin wrapper around [new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

The allocator in your example appears to be a hybrid [sub](http://www.memorymanagement.org/mmref/alloc.html#suballocators)/bump(increment) allocator. In summary, it allocates a chunk of memory from the system if allocator memory is exhausted, then bump allocates from an available chunk.

Among other things, consider:

- It's not thread-safe. Concurrent access would eventually corrupt it. This doesn't matter for isolated profiling using a single thread, but is an important consideration nonetheless.
- It manually manages memory all over the place. i.e. `Chunk` manages memory yet doesn't have a destructor, requiring `Chunk::release` to be called to destroy it(i.e.
  in `~FixedAllocator()`). Avoid manual memory management(even when writing allocators) utilizing [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization):

  ```
  class Chunk
  {
      // private: not required, classes are private by default.
      friend class FixedAllocator;

      // Replaced init(...) with constructor.
      Chunk(size_t blockSize, uchar block) :
          pData(new uchar[blockSize * blocks]),
          firstAvailableBlock(0),
          blocksAvailable(blocks) 
      {
          uchar* p = pData; 
          for (uchar i = 0; i != blocks; p += blockSize) 
          {
              *p = ++i;
          }
      }
      Chunk(const Chunk& other) = delete; // Disable copy construction.
      Chunk(Chunk&& other) :
          pData(std::move(other.pData)),
          firstAvailableBlock(other.firstAvailableBlock),
          blocksAvailable(other.blocksAvailable) 
      { 
          other.firstAvailableBlock = 0;
          other.blocksAvailable = 0;
      }

      Chunk& operator=(const Chunk&& other) = delete; // Disable copy assignment.
      Chunk& operator=(Chunk&& other)
      {
          pData = std::move(other.pData);
          firstAvailableBlock = other.firstAvailableBlock;
          blocksAvailable = other.blocksAvailable;
          other.firstAvailableBlock = 0;
          other.blocksAvailable = 0;
          return *this;
      }

      //...
      void release()
      {
          pData.reset();
      }
      //...

      std::unique_ptr<uchar[]> pData; // Automatically deleted in the implicitly generated destructor.
      uchar firstAvailableBlock, blocksAvailable; 
  };

  // And of course don't forget to update chunk creation:
  //...
  Chunk newChunk(blockSize, blocks);
  chunks.push_back(std::move(newChunk));
  //...
  ```
- `Chunk::hasBlock` doesn't account for holes. If you were to allocate 10 bytes/5 bytes/10 bytes, then later deallocate the 5 byte block, `hasBlock` would return `false` for ranges within the 5 byte block, even though that space is actually available. Properly fixing that requires a system to track allocations.

It's slower because it's doing more overall work than the typical `std::allocator` implementation.

- The small object size is set to `sizeof(int)`,
  which is most likely 4. The size of a `std::list` node is at least 12(back ptr(4-8), forward ptr(4-8), object(4+)). Thus, at least with the list nodes, `SmallObjAllocator::allocate()` and `SmallObjAllocator::deallocate()` won't call `new` or `delete`, instead always calling `FixedAllocator::allocate()` and `FixedAllocator::deallocate()`.
- `FixedAllocator::allocate()` and `FixedAllocator::deallocate()` are slow. They both execute a linear search, which in the worst case means they iterate over all chunks. Even in the average case, a lot of time is spent in the allocator instead of your program. Optimizing those two functions will yield the most results.
- The `blockSize` of your allocator is set to `sizeof(int) * 10000`(probably 40k). Therefore, 10k insertions into an `std::list<int>` requires at least 120kb(`sizeof(node) * 10000`), so it's likely `FixedAllocator` resizes at least twice in your example(assuming a doubling resize policy). You can eliminate resizing by setting `blockSize` high enough that a resize is never required.
  `Allocator<int, 100000>`(100k) should be more than enough for your example.

Allocators are a very complex subject, and honestly there are too many details to go over to fully explain how to optimize your example without writing a short novel. I recommend reading up on allocator design and studying allocators used in the real world to gain a better understanding of the subject.

See:

- [The Art & Science of Memory Allocation](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~porter/courses/cse506/f12/slides/malloc.pdf)
- [Memory management](http://www.memorymanagement.org/index.html)
- [Memory allocators 101](http://jamesgolick.com/2013/5/15/memory-allocators-101.html)
- [Memory allocators wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#ALLOCATION)
- [How to allocate memory](http://geocar.sdf1.org/alloc.html)
- [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)
- [jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc)
- [rpmalloc](https://github.com/rampantpixels/rpmalloc)